# How to Set up custom recurring payment service using paypal direct payment NPV API c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm implementing subscription payment in my application, I want to implement recurring payment using paypal. But I cannot stick to the paypal recurring payment profile,because I want my application to handle all the payments by itself. I'm using NVP API and Permission service by paypal. Please help me with a sample code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [here](https://github.com/paypal/) and search Merchant, and there are several available developing language for you. In this sample, you could check the recurring payments and Direct payment. In addition, adding the [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/#id08669F0705Z) for Direct Payment for Recurring payment for your easy reference.

Comment: I had already gone through the documents, but what I need is different, I want to set up custom recurring payments without using 'PayPal Recurring payments'.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "custom recurring payments"? If you need to charge buyer varying amount at varying interval, please check if below Reference Transaction should meet your demand.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/

- To enable this feature , you need to contact PayPal local customer service.